# Change color of button inside active NavLink (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<NavLink exact to="/">
  <Button>
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} />
  </Button>
</NavLink>
```

I know I can add `activeClassName` to the `NavLink`, however, what I want to achieve is that I want to change the color of the FontAwesome `icon` inside the `Button` when it's active. The `activeClassName` on the `NavLink` will not change the color of the icon.

Comment: could you add a selector for the icon in your css? `.active .icon { color: blue };`?

Comment: that works, awesome! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide color property on icon. Let's say you have icon which has class `fa-home` and it is inside `activeClassName` so the css would be:

```
.activeClassName .fa-home {
 color: red;
}
```